# Is the 2-norm of a matrix bounded by the maximum of its 1-norm and Infinity-norm?

Tags: linear-algebra, normed-spaces, upper-lower-bounds, matrix-norms

I am implementing the algorithm in "Approximating the Logarithm of a Matrix to Specified Accuracy" by Sheung Hun Cheng, Nicholas J. Higham, Charles S. Kenny, Alan J. Laub, 2001.

In this algorithm, I would to avoid computing the 2-norm of a real-valued square matrix $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$. Numerical experiments suggest to me that the following upper bound holds

$\|A\|_2 \leq \max ( \|A\|_1, \|A\|_\infty )$

Can anybody confirm whether this inequality always holds? Thank you and happy new year!

One user remarked that Cauchy-Schwarz implies

$\|A\|_2 \leq \sqrt n \min ( \|A\|_1, \|A\|_\infty )$

which in some cases improves the bound, but not always. So I hope my initial question is still of relevance. A counter example to the suggested inequality would also be appreciated, if it exists.

Comment: [This post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/484779/matrix-norm-bounds) may be helpful. Happy new year!

Comment: The title needs correction.

Comment: thank you very much for your feedback! cauchy schwarz indeed sometimes improves the bound (and i have included that term in my implementation), but not always.

Comment: What are these norms? Entrywise? So this is just a question about vectors?

Comment: You can find the formulas for the matrix norms in the section "Special cases" on the following page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm

Comment: So to clarify is $\|A\|_1$ the maximum column sum of absolute entries of $A$. And $\|A\|_\infty$ the maximum row sum of absolute entries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed:

$\|A\|_2 \leq \max ( \|A\|_1, \|A\|_\infty )$

follows from

$\|A\|_2 \leq \sqrt { \|A\|_1  \|A\|_\infty } \leq \max ( \|A\|_1, \|A\|_\infty )$

which - according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm) - is a special case of Hölder's inequality.

Comment: I am not sure if the inequality follows from the wikipedia's Hölder's inequality. There, $\|\cdot\|_p$ is the Schatten norm, and the definitions of $\|\cdot\|_2$ and $\|\cdot\|_\infty$ are different from what's being asked.